# Query Bulk Data Load Jobs once completed

Tags: bulk-api

Can someone tell me how to query the data which is displayed in " Monitor Bulk Data Load Jobs" Section "Completed last 7 days"

Answer (score 2):

It seems the functionality is not exposed by Salesforce at all. 
Those objects are not avialable in APEX. As I checked all Apex supported objects(with globalDescribe)  and none of them have "750" as object prefix.
Also as far as I know the bulk API endpoints also do not support listing of the jobs. You only can access the jobs by providing JobId.
[Bulk API Walkthrough](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_code_curl_walkthrough.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any orgs with bulk jobs to look at off hand to figure out exactly which fields are the ones displayed, but this should help you get started:

```
SELECT CompletedDate, Id, JobItemsProcessed, Status FROM AsyncApexJob
WHERE CompletedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:7
```

Comment: AsyncApexJobs doe not include bulk data load jobs

Answer (score 0):

Send an HTTP callout to the Bulk API v2.0, REST and JSON enabled.  Not that bad.

```
final String VERSION_BULKJOB_WAS_MADE_WITH = 'v53.0';
final Id ASYNCAPIJOB_ID = '750000123456789';
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
String endPointUrl = URL.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/data/' + VERSION_BULKJOB_WAS_MADE_WITH + '/jobs/ingest/' + ASYNCAPIJOB_ID;
req.setEndpoint(endPointUrl);
req.setMethod('GET');
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse response = http.send(req);
String respBody = response.getBody();
System.debug('respBody: ' + respBody);
```

Sample response:

```
{
    "id": "750000123456789",
    "operation": "insert",
    "object": "MyObject__c",
    "createdById": "005000000012345AAA",
    "createdDate": "2022-02-19T03:00:36.000+0000",
    "systemModstamp": "2022-02-19T03:01:46.000+0000",
    "state": "JobComplete",
    "concurrencyMode": "Parallel",
    "contentType": "CSV",
    "apiVersion": 53,
    "jobType": "V2Ingest",
    "lineEnding": "LF",
    "columnDelimiter": "PIPE",
    "numberRecordsProcessed": 10293,
    "numberRecordsFailed": 0,
    "retries": 0,
    "totalProcessingTime": 66100,
    "apiActiveProcessingTime": 59388,
    "apexProcessingTime": 0
}
```

Hope that helps!